# Using java classes in package (vim + eclim)

Tags: java, vim, eclim

When you create new java class with vim, save it and leave it open on seperate vim instance, apparently you can't use that class untill that vim instance with opened class is closed.

**Update:**
Or not... Tried to replicate issue but now it just works... Haven't changed anything.
Just added new class to package, and I can use it from Main.java...

**Problem solved.**

I have a package `org.test` and in that package there are the `Main.java` and `Test.java` classes.

But for some reason `Main.java` (which has the main method) can't find the `Test.java` class (which, I repeat, are both in the same package).

I tried `import org.test.*;`, but still nothing...

here's code (if necessary)

Main.java

```
package org.test;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test newTest = new Test();
    }
}
```

Test.java

```
package org.test;

public class Test{

// doesn't matter if anything is here
}
```

In Main.java I get

```
Test cannot be resolved to a type.
```

Any help? Everything works when I don't use a package.

If it helps, when I try in Main:

```
import org.test.Test;
```

autocomplete doesn't find Test and when I save file I get error

```
The import org.test.Test cannot be resolved.
```

One more time: both Main.java and Test.java in same package (org.test).

Maybe I need change something in settings? I assume eclipse everything does automagicaly in this case, but I don't really know what and where should I change...

Comment: Is this appropriately tagged?

Comment: Maybe you mix up classes and files. Could we see some code?

Comment: Try importing all the classes individually.

Comment: Properly tagged, I'm using vim with eclim.

Answer (score 0):

When you create new java class with vim, save it and leave it open on seperate vim instance, apparently you can't use that class untill that vim instance with opened class is closed.

**Update:** Or not... Tried to replicate issue but now it just works... Haven't changed anything. Just added new class to package, and I can use it from Main.java...

**Problem solved.**